# float to double giving Strange results

Tags: java, double

I came across with this behavior of float and double during type casting.

I modified my actual statements to better understanding.

**1**

```
System.out.println((double)((float)(128.12301)));//Output:128.12301635712188
```

Same output all the time.

**2**

```
System.out.println((double)((float)(128888.12301)));//Output:128888.125
```

Both outputs are strange for me I can't understand how it's working.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What *exactly* is strange about it for you?

Comment: @JonSkeet 12888.125 ??specially why 125 and why extra numbers in the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *several* steps involved here, each with different numbers. Let's split the code up for each statement:

```
double original = 128.12301; // Or 128888.12301
float floatValue = (float) original;
double backToDouble = (double) floatValue;
System.out.println(backToDouble);
```

So for each number, the steps are:

1. Compile time: Convert the decimal value in the source code into the nearest exact `double` value
2. Execution time: Convert the `double` value to the nearest exact `float` value
3. Execution time: Convert the `float` value into a `double` value (this never loses any information)
4. Execution time: Convert the final `double` value into a string

Steps 1 and 2 can lose information; step 4 doesn't always print the *exact* value - it just follows what [`Double.toString(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-) does.

So let's take 128.12301 as an example. That's converted at compile-time to exactly 128.123009999999993624442140571773052215576171875. Then the conversion to `float` yields exactly 128.123016357421875. So after the conversion *back* to `double` (which preserves the value) we print out 128.123016357421875. That prints 128.12301635712188 because that's the fewest digits in can print out without being ambiguous between that value and the nearest `double` value greater than or less than it.

Now with 128888.12301, the exact `double` value is 128888.123009999995701946318149566650390625 - and the closest `float` to that is exactly
128888.125. After converting that back to a `double`, the *exact* value of that `double` is printed out because there are other exact `double` values near it.

Basically, the result will depend on how many significant digits you've included to start with, and how much information is lost when it rounds to the nearest `double` and then to the nearest `float`.

Comment: @TAsk: I've added a bit more, with the examples you've given.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(number)` will go through [`Double.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29) which is a fairly complex method (as seen in its documentation) an will not always behave as you'd expect. It basically gives the shortest string which uniquely determines `number`.

> How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of m or a? There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type double. That is, suppose that x is the exact mathematical value represented by the decimal representation produced by this method for a finite nonzero argument d. Then d must be the double value nearest to x; or if two double values are equally close to x, then d must be one of them and the least significant bit of the significant of d must be 0.

Answer (score 0):

A float is a 32 bit IEEE 754 floating point.

A double is a 64 bit IEEE 754 floating point.

It is the same for float and double, both are binary floating point types, but double has more precision than float.

Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for more details